# targeting the images and the content in a post separately

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

In my WP theme I want to be able to target (to hang the css in my style.css) the images and content in my single.php.

On single.php it puts the content in through the loop

```
  <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
        <?php bnNav_content_nav( 'nav-below' ); ?>

  <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

and on content-single.php

```
<div class="container"
  <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

the content of the post has images and text, but are all outputted in < p > tags. I can target the images sort of to be able to add -margins (messy but then I can have different side margins for the text) But I want to add more uniques styles to each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your images don't have to be wrapped in paragraphs. You can use the WordPress editor in text-mode to wrap the the images in DIVs.

[image]

This way you can define styles for the DIVs with images and paragraphs seperatly. If you need this function often you can prepare yourself a quicktag which will insert a `div` with an image in it for you quickly, even in editors' visual mode.

The [AddQuicktag-Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/addquicktag/) is a nice tool to work with.

Comment: didn't know I could do this. It's a bit of extra work but seems easiest solution

Comment: Glad to help. It is extra work - with a quicktag you can minimize it. You don't have do use  a <div> if something other fits your needs better - you can also use <figure> or <p class="p-with-image">.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there's no specific function to grab media from [post body](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content). You could use [regex for wrapping/handling images](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/219067-expression-to-replace-the-class-attribute-in-an-image/) in post content or you could do it with just CSS like this:

```
.container p img {
 /*styles here*/
    }
```

Also since you mentioned jQuery, you can access post images node list in the same selector way:

```
$('.container p img').each(function(){
   //$(this) is and <img tag
})
```

Comment: Like I mentioned I can do '.container p img {' to target images. I want to add margins, padding, etc. to just the text and not the images. But they are both wrapped in < p > tags

Comment: Then you can check with jquery : $(".content p").each( function () { if (!$(this).find(".img").length) { //has no images }});